# Microsoft Graph api responsible for creating notifications doesn’t work on mobile

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am working with below MS Graph API.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/7155e3c8-175e-4311-97ef-572edc3aa3db/sendActivityNotification
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "topic": {
        "source": "text",
        "value": "Weekly Virtual Social",
        "webUrl": "Teams webUrl"
    },
    "previewText": {
        "content": "It will be fun!"
    },
    "activityType": "eventCreated",
    "recipient": {
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.channelMembersNotificationRecipient",
        "teamId": "7155e3c8-175e-4311-97ef-572edc3aa3db",
        "channelId": "19:0ea5de04de4743bcb4cd20cb99235d99@thread.tacv2"
    }
}
```

Documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications

I am **successfully** able to run the API for my bot application in **Teams Desktop APP** - meaning the notifications created by the app are visible in the activity feed in the MS desktop app.

But the **same** notifications are **not** **seen** in the **mobile app of MS Teams** for both Android and iOS.

**To be noted**: I can see the push notification on the iOS but if click on the banner it opens up the Teams App but that particular notification is not present there.

**Is that the limitation from the API or something else that needed to be configured?**

Comment: We tried with this [graph-activity-feed sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs). We are able to see notifications in Android in group chat scope - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ3Mj.png

Comment: Please go through this thread for more information - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433896/ms-teams-activity-feed-notifications-dont-arrive-to-mobile. Please let us know if that helps?

Comment: did you tried with `topic.source = text`?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is quite strange here, If the payload has a topic like below that is `"source": "text"` will show the push notifications but not in the feed.

```
"topic": {        
  "source": "text",
  "value": "Weekly Virtual Social",
  "webUrl": "Teams webUrl"
},
```

But, after updating the topic like below `source: 'entityUrl'` works and show the notifications in the feed.

```
topic: {
   source: 'entityUrl',
   value: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/...../`,
},
```

Just a note, if one wants to link the notification to a certain message - meaning if you click the notification it'll take to that particular message. Use the below value.

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/${team_id}/channels/${channel_id}/messages/${reply_to_id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/$%7Bteam_id%7D/channels/$%7Bchannel_id%7D/messages/$%7Breply_to_id%7D)